# Table rows not visible within <tbody>. How could search filter be implemented in this table?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to build a table based on this example: http://demo.webslesson.info/multiple-checkbox-update-data/
https://www.webslesson.info/2018/09/update-multiple-rows-with-checkbox-in-php-using-ajax-jquery.html

It works fine, however I'm struggling with adding a search field to enable search across table rows.

I've tried adding search field, but it didn't work because table rows are not listed within tbody tag, but called dynamically from ajax and not sure what would be the best way to teach my search field to interact with the table rows listed as results from script below. Would someone be able to help me with this? Thanks in advance!

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
 <form method="post" id="update_form">
 <div align="left">
 <input type="submit" name="multiple_update" id="multiple_update" class="btn btn-info" value="Multiple Update" />
 </div>
 <br />
 <div class="table-responsive">
 <table id="mirror" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
 <thead>
 <th width="5%"></th>
<th width="20%">Name</th>
<th width="30%">Address</th>
<th width="15%">Gender</th>
<th width="20%">Designation</th>
<th width="10%">Age</th>
</thead>
 <tbody></tbody>
 </table>
</div>
</form>
</div>  
</div>
</body>   
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  

function fetch_data()
{
$.ajax({
url:"select.php",
method:"POST",
dataType:"json",
success:function(data)
{
var html = '';
for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
{
html += '<tr>';
html += '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+data[count].id+'" data- name="'+data[count].name+'" data-address="'+data[count].address+'" data-gender="'+data[count].gender+'" data-designation="'+data[count].designation+'" data-age="'+data[count].age+'" class="check_box"  /></td>';
html += '<td>'+data[count].name+'</td>';
html += '<td>'+data[count].address+'</td>';
html += '<td>'+data[count].gender+'</td>';
html += '<td>'+data[count].designation+'</td>';
html += '<td>'+data[count].age+'</td></tr>';
}
$('tbody').html(html);
}
});
}

fetch_data();

$(document).on('click', '.check_box', function(){
var html = '';
if(this.checked)
{
html = '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" data-name="'+$(this).data('name')+'" data-address="'+$(this).data('address')+'" data-gender="'+$(this).data('gender')+'" data-designation="'+$(this).data('designation')+'" data-age="'+$(this).data('age')+'" class="check_box" checked /></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control"   value="'+$(this).data("name")+'" /></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="address[]" class="form-control" value="'+$(this).data("address")+'" /></td>';
html += '<td><select name="gender[]" id="gender_'+$(this).attr('id')+'" class="form-control"><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="designation[]" class="form-control" value="'+$(this).data("designation")+'" /></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="age[]" class="form-control" value="'+$(this).data("age")+'" /><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id[]" value="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" /></td>';
}
else
{
html = '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" data-name="'+$(this).data('name')+'" data-address="'+$(this).data('address')+'" data-gender="'+$(this).data('gender')+'" data-designation="'+$(this).data('designation')+'" data-age="'+$(this).data('age')+'" class="check_box" /></td>';
html += '<td>'+$(this).data('name')+'</td>';
html += '<td>'+$(this).data('address')+'</td>';
html += '<td>'+$(this).data('gender')+'</td>';
html += '<td>'+$(this).data('designation')+'</td>';
html += '<td>'+$(this).data('age')+'</td>';            
}
$(this).closest('tr').html(html);

$('#gender_'+$(this).attr('id')+'').val($(this).data('gender'));
});

$('#update_form').on('submit', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
if($('.check_box:checked').length > 0)
{
$.ajax({
url:"multiple_update.php",
method:"POST",
data:$(this).serialize(),
success:function()
{
alert('Data Updated');
fetch_data();
}
})
}
});

});  
</script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
table = document.getElementById("mirror");
tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
if (td) {
txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
tr[i].style.display = "";
} else {
tr[i].style.display = "none";
}
}       
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea for a search field.

After searching a given string, the results will appear in the `searchResults` div. The script searches through every cell in the `tbody` element, that hasn't got any child elements - that way the cells with checkboxes are being ignored.

As a search criterion I'm using a simple regular expression, that matches every string that contains the searched value.

Add this part below your form:

```
<form>
  <input id="searchInput" type="text" name="search" />
  <button id="searchBtn">Search</button>
</form>
<div id="searchResults"></div>
```

And this in `script` tag:

```
$('#searchBtn').on('click', (e) => {

  e.preventDefault()
  $('#searchResults').html('')

  const searchedVal = $('#searchInput').val()
  const tableRows = $('tbody tr')

  tableRows.each(row => {

    const columns = $(tableRows[row]).find('td')
    columns.each(col => {
      const columnContent = $(columns[col]).html()
      const columnChildren = $(columns[col]).children().length

      if (columnChildren > 0) return

      const regex = new RegExp('.*' + searchedVal + '.*')
      const match = columnContent.match(regex)
      match != null && $('#searchResults').append(`<p>Found in row ${row + 1}, column ${col + 1}: ${columnContent}</p>`)

    })

  })

})
```

Comment: Hi Christoph, I've tried what you have proposed, however it didn't return any value within:<div id="searchResults"></div> tag.

Comment: I just edited my above post and added the search filter I was trying to add into the above table. I could see that it was interacting with the table, but unable to find 'tr' attribute. Any solution to this? :) thank you for your help!